# Checking a file existence on a remote SSH server using Python

Tags: python, file-io, file-exists

I have two servers A and B. I'm suppose to send, let said an image file, from server A to another server B. But before server A could send the file over I would like to check if a similar file exist in server B. I try using os.path.exists() and it does not work.

```
print os.path.exists('ubuntu@serverB.com:b.jpeg')
```

The result return a false even I have put an exact file on server B. I'm not sure whether is it my syntax error or is there any better solution to this problem. Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "a server"? Is it an ssh server? I'm pretty sure the `os.path` module does not understand any network protocols. Of course, if the network path is mounted somewhere in your file system then you can access it via its path.

Answer (score 23):

The `os.path` functions only work on files on the same computer.  They operate on *paths*, and `ubuntu@serverB.com:b.jpeg` is not a path.

In order to accomplish this, you will need to remotely execute a script.  Something like this will work, usually:

```
def exists_remote(host, path):
    """Test if a file exists at path on a host accessible with SSH."""
    status = subprocess.call(
        ['ssh', host, 'test -f {}'.format(pipes.quote(path))])
    if status == 0:
        return True
    if status == 1:
        return False
    raise Exception('SSH failed')
```

So you can get if a file exists on another server with:

```
if exists_remote('ubuntu@serverB.com', 'b.jpeg'):
    # it exists...
```

Note that this will probably be *incredibly* slow, likely even more than 100 ms.

Comment: `return subprocess.call(['ssh', host, 'test -e ' + pipes.quote(path)]) == 0`

Comment: Here are a few options: `test -e` to see if any file exists (directory or regular file), `test -f` to see if it exists and is a regular file, or `test -d` to see if it exists and is a directory.

Comment: This seems to break for paths including `$HOME/test` or `~/test`. Do you know why?

Comment: @jvriesem: Because there is no directory named `$HOME`, and no directory named `~` either. It turns out that `$HOME/test` is not actually the path to a file. Instead, you have to replace `$HOME` with the value of the `HOME` environment variable, and once you do that, you get the path to a file. The operating system will not do this for you.

Comment: The complication is that if you are testing for a file on a remote computer, you need the value of the `HOME` environment variable *on that computer.* You can do this by allowing shell expansion, but there are potential **major security risks** involved with allowing shell expansion.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: How would one allow shell expansion? If it's for a script between my laptop and a workstation I or a colleague use, are the security risks worthy of consideration?

Comment: @jvriesem: You might want to open a separate question for this, since it's complicated. The gist of it is that instead of running `test -f '~/abc def'`, you can change the quoting so it becomes `test -f ~/'abc def'`, or perhaps just `test -f 'abc def'`. Your Python code has to parse the path and convert it correctly, if you want it to work this way. You may also prefer to use a protocol like SFTP, which is usually available if SSH is available.

Comment: What's happening here is that you're making the shell on the remote end convert the path to the format you want.